# Liferay DXP: adding java class to theme

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-7

Until now I have always provided my theme with some sort of NavigationUtil-Class written in Java and put under `docroot\WEB-INF\src`.

I upgraded my theme to Liferay DXP using the *Theme Generator* and *blade cli*.
Now the java class does not seem to get registered as it used to in a normal sdk project.

Do I have to seperate it from the theme now or are there other ways to integrate java into theme?

Comment: As Liferay's new Theme's SDK does not handle Java, and uses Node to build the theme, I'd suspect you'll need to build/deploy your Java code separately.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that there is a mechanism that turns your themes "WEB-INF/src" into "WEB-INF/classes" when you "gulp deploy", so I wondered...

Comment: @Byrån Can I use java from my theme like I used to with the objectUtil? I need it to build custom navigation, but I only see descriptions on how to setup dependencies for modules, not for themes...

Comment: Can you provide some sample code, demonstrating what you want to do?

Comment: I found the solution in templating context contributor. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of research I stumbled upon [Template Context Contributor](https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/template-context-contributor), which can provide variables into the theming/templating context really easily.

For anyone else who is interested, read this tutorial: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/context-contributors

Cheers!